# How do I align information on a title page?

Tags: horizontal-alignment, color, titles

This is the code I'm using to create the title page of my thesis and I want the middle part with my name and my information alongwith my supervisor to be aligned. I dont know if I should use the equation and aligned option, it wrote it out like a chemical formula. Please could someone help me, so that it is clearly aligned.

```
Name         : Jane Doe
CID          : 0128678493
Programme    : MSc in Genetic Epidemiology
Academic Year: 2016-2017
Supervisor   : Dr Maike Takanaka
```

Also, how do I get them to be displayed in Imperial Blue colour?

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper,oneside]{book}
    \usepackage[bindingoffset=1.5cm, left=3cm, right=3cm, top=3cm, bottom=3cm]{geometry}
    \usepackage{lmodern}
    \usepackage{titling}
    \usepackage{setspace}\doublespacing
    \usepackage{float}
    \usepackage{amsmath,amssymb,amsthm}
    \usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
    \usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
    \usepackage[labelfont=bf]{caption}
    \usepackage [english]{babel}
    \usepackage{xpatch}
    \usepackage{bm}
    \usepackage{tabularx}
    \usepackage{graphicx}
    \usepackage[scaled]{uarial}
    \usepackage[section]{placeins}
    \usepackage[dvipsnames]{xcolor}
    \usepackage{fancyhdr}
    \usepackage{tikz}
    \pagestyle{fancy} %<- setting the headers and footers. 
    \fancyhf{}
    \fancyhead[RO]{\slshape \rightmark}
    \fancyfoot[C]{\thepage} 
    \setcounter{secnumdepth}{4}
    \begin{document} 
    \begin{titlepage}
    \begin{figure}[h]
    \flushleft
      \includegraphics[width=3in]{/Users/archanaramesh/Desktop/asd-metabolon/dissertation/figures/Logo.pdf}
     \end{figure}
     \begin{center}
    \ \Huge{\textbf {Profiling Effects}}\\ 
    \vspace{0.5cm}
     \Large{Name : Jane Doe} \\
     \Large{CID: 0128678493} \\
     \Large{Programme : MSc in Genetic Epidemiology} \\
     \Large{Academic Year: 2016-2017} \\
     \Large{Supervisor: Dr Maike Takanaka }\\
      \vspace{0.5cm}
     \large{\textbf{{Statement of Originality}}}\\
     \end{center}
        This project report is submitted in partial fulfilment of the requirements for award of MSc in Genetic Epidemiology, Imperial College London. I hereby confirm that it is an original work, representing my own academic effort and that all sources have been fully acknowledged.\\
    \textbf {Signature:  }\\
    \textbf{Date:  }\
    \end {titlepage}
    \end {document}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Something like this?

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper,oneside]{book}
    \usepackage[bindingoffset=1.5cm, left=3cm, right=3cm, top=3cm, bottom=3cm]{geometry}
    \usepackage{lmodern}
    \usepackage{titling}
    \usepackage{setspace}\doublespacing
    \usepackage{float}
    \usepackage{amsmath,amssymb,amsthm}
    \usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
    \usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
    \usepackage[labelfont=bf]{caption}
    \usepackage [english]{babel}
    \usepackage{xpatch}
    \usepackage{bm}
    \usepackage{tabularx}
    \usepackage{graphicx}
    \usepackage[scaled]{uarial}
    \usepackage[section]{placeins}
    \usepackage[dvipsnames]{xcolor}
    \definecolor{imperial}{RGB}{22, 20, 128}
    \usepackage{fancyhdr}
    \usepackage{tikz}
    \pagestyle{fancy} %<- setting the headers and footers. 
    \fancyhf{}
    \fancyhead[RO]{\slshape \rightmark}
    \fancyfoot[C]{\thepage} 
    \setcounter{secnumdepth}{4}
    \begin{document} 
    \begin{titlepage}
    \begin{figure}[h]
    \flushleft
      \includegraphics[width=3in]{example-image-a}
     \end{figure}
     \begin{center}
    \ \Huge{\textbf {Profiling Effects}}\\ 
    \begin{center}
    \Large\textcolor{imperial}{%
    \begin{tabular}{l@{}ll}
     Name & : & Jane Doe \\
     CID & : & 0128678493 \\
     Programme & : & MSc in Genetic Epidemiology \\
     Academic Year & : & 2016-2017  \\
     Supervisor & : & Dr Maike Takanaka \\
    \end{tabular}
    }
     \end{center}

    \large{\textbf{{Statement of Originality}}}\\
     \end{center}
        This project report is submitted in partial fulfilment of the requirements for award of MSc in Genetic Epidemiology, Imperial College London. I hereby confirm that it is an original work, representing my own academic effort and that all sources have been fully acknowledged.\\
    \textbf {Signature:  }\\
    \textbf{Date:  }\
    \end {titlepage}
    \end {document}
```

[image]

Comment: @Ar1229 You're welcome, thank you for accepting my answer!